# o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ERROR: syntax error at or near "("

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jpql

I am trying to make an user API but I am getting above error for my simple query. Please find my below codes.

In logs I am getting this as error

```
Hibernate: Select new  UserResponse(u.user_id,u.user_name,u.password) from public."DetailsCompany" u where user_id =?
2020-08-26 20:31:49.078  WARN 26274 --- [nio-7071-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2020-08-26 20:31:49.078 ERROR 26274 --- [nio-7071-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>{
  @Query(value="Select new  UserResponse(u.user_id,u.user_name,u.password) from public.\"DetailsCompany\" u where user_id =:id",nativeQuery = true)
  public UserResponse findUserById(@Param("id")Integer id);
}

UserResponse.java
package com.company.user.Response;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserResponse{
    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
}
#As requested Entity Class Details#
#UserEntity.java#
package com.company.user.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="DetailsCompany", schema = "public")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
private Integer userId;
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an HQL to a native query. Change nativeQuery to false.

Change your query to

```
@Query(value="Select new  com.company.user.Response.UserResponse(u.userId,u.userName,u.password) from UserEntity u where u.userId =:id",nativeQuery = false)
```

Comment: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.company.user.Response.UserResponse com.company.user.Repository.UserRepository.findUserById(java.lang.Integer)!, after making it false I am getting the above exception

Comment: Your query has errors. Check UserResponse class constructor and DetailsCompany mapping, is it correct? Also, i think you can remove the double quotes.

Comment: I am using lombok and applying all annotations for constructors for three fields

Comment: And after removing double quotes: ERROR: relation "public.detailscompany" does not exist

Comment: Can you post your DetailsCompany class?

Comment: Please find above classes I have declared

Answer (score 1):

The constructor name must be fully qualified. Try using com.your.package.UserResponse

Comment: I already tried this but this is not resolving my problem

Comment: `SELECT new UserResponse(u.user_id,u.user_name,u.password) FROM {h-schema}DetailsCompany u WHERE user_id =:id",nativeQuery = true`.
can you try this one? @Gaurav